# In what way do I have to assign ports for group chat in android?

Tags: android, sockets, port, messenger, groupchat

I'm a beginner of programming study,

I started to study socket programming,

and I want to make sure that I understood correctly about concept of socket.

My questions are as below,

**1) To code group chat, is one port number for one group room?**

**2) Then, how do I aasign port numbers which are not occupied automatically?**

**3) What if I use all the port numbers?**

Thank you,

jgom from South Korea

Comment: If multicast, one multicast port is enough. If unicast, one unicast port is enough for connection with multiple clients. If more than one room, each room must have one unicast port. You can set all needed unicast ports from a config file. But, for group room which I assume is dynamically created, you need to dynamically create a unicast port unique by increment as long as it is still free.

Comment: Then, one more question. socketserver and socket share port numbers right?